# Why aren't 10 and 100 considered Kaprekar numbers?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, number-theory

I'm trying to do the Modified Kaprekar Numbers problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kaprekar-numbers) which describes a Kaprekar number by

> Here's an explanation from Wikipedia about the ORIGINAL Kaprekar
>   Number (spot the difference!): In mathematics, a Kaprekar number for a
>   given base is a non-negative integer, the representation of whose
>   square in that base can be split into two parts that add up to the
>   original number again. For instance, 45 is a Kaprekar number, because
>   45² = 2025 and 20+25 = 45.

and what I don't understand is why 10 and 100 aren't Kaprekar numbers.

10^2 = 1000 and 10 + 00 = 10

Right?

So my solution

```
// Returns the number represented by the digits 
// in the range arr[i], arr[i + 1], ..., arr[j - 1].
// If there are no elements in range, return 0.
static int NumberInRange(int[] arr, int i, int j)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(; i < j; ++i)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}

// Returns true or false depending on whether k 
// is a Kaprekar number. 
// Example: IsKaprekar(45) = true because 45^2=2025 and 20+25=45
// Example: IsKaprekar(9) = false because the set of the split 
//                          digits of 7^2=49 are {49,0},{4,9} and
//                          neither of 49+0 or 4+9 equal 7.
static bool IsKaprekar(int k)
{
    int square = k * k;
    int[] digits = square.ToString().Select(c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < digits.Length; ++i)
    {
        int right = NumberInRange(digits, 0, i);
        int left = NumberInRange(digits, i, digits.Length);
        if((right + left) == k)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

is saying all the Kaprekar numbers between 1 and 100 are

```
1 9 10 45 55 99 100
```

whereas the "right" answer is

```
1 9 45 55 99
```

Comment: "By convention, the second part may start with the digit 0, but must be nonzero." Refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734489/why-is-10-not-a-kaprekar-number

Comment: 10x10=100 and not 1000

Comment: @PM77-1 Wow, I'm an idiot. But my point remains.

Comment: Just read the definition of a [Kaprekar number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number) on Wikipedia. The article explains why that exact example is not a Kaprekar number. Also, this is not really a programming question it's just maths

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because 10 x 10 = 100. Then you substring the right part with a length equals d = 2, that is digit count of original value (10), then the left part would be 1.

So l = 1 and r = 00, l + r = 1, that is not equals to 10.

The same for 100. 100 x 100 = 10000. l = 10, r = 000, so l + r = 10 not equal 100.

Here is my solution in JAVA.

```
static void kaprekarNumbers(int p, int q) {

    long[] result = IntStream.rangeClosed(p, q).mapToLong(Long::valueOf)
            .filter(v -> {
                int d = String.valueOf(v).length();
                Long sq = v * v;
                String sqSt = sq.toString();
                if (sqSt.length() > 1) {
                    long r = Long.parseLong(sqSt.substring(sqSt.length() - d));
                    long l = Long.parseLong(sqSt.substring(0, sqSt.length() - d));
                    return r + l == v;
                } else return v == 1;
            }).toArray();

    if (result.length > 0) {
        for (long l : result) {
            System.out.print(l + " ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("INVALID RANGE");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 100+00 the right is 00, which is wrong because in a kaprekar number the right may start with zero (ex: 025) but cannot be entirely 0.

Therefore you can put a condition in the loop that

```
if(right==0)
     return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

```
static bool IsKaprekar(int k)
{
    int t;
    for (int digits = new String(k).length(); digits > 0; digits--, t *= 10);
    long sq = k * k;
    long first = sq / t;
    long second = sq % t;
    return k == first + second;
}
```

1. find a number to divide and mod the square with in order to split it.  This number should be a factor of 10 based on the number of digits in the original number.
2. calculate the square.
3. split the square.
4. compare the original to the sum of the splits.